# How to create PHP Array from Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, implode

I am trying to create an array from a MySQL query that I have.
This is to update facebook status' with the access tokens I have stored in my MySQL database.
I am able to pull the access tokens without problem, but am having trouble creating an array that will list them as follows:
`array('token1', 'token2'..etc)`
I have formatted the array to implode and give '' and a , but it still will not work.
any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT access_token 
                        FROM demographic 
                        ORDER BY access_token ASC");
while($access_token_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
  $list_access_token[] = $access_token_array['access_token']; 
}

$comma_separated_quote = ("'" . implode("', '", $list_access_token) . "'");
$arr = array ($comma_separated_quote);  

foreach ($arr as $tokens) {
  $facebook->api('/me/feed','POST',array('access_token' => $str,'message' => 'test'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am reading this wrong but it looks like you want this...

```
<?php
$results = mysql_query("SELECT access_token FROM demographic ORDER BY access_token ASC");
while($access_token_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', array('access_token' => $access_token_array['access_token'], 'message' => 'test'));

}
?>
```

Are you trying to post a message for every access_token?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you already have what you want in the $access_token_array.  I don't understand why you then add it to an array, implode & parse it, and then enumerate the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the **$str** with **$tokens** and it should work.